# What's the easiest way to create a QR code for a link?

Tags: qr-code

The title is pretty self explanatory on this one.

Comment: While Android can read QR codes, how is this an Android question? Certainly I see a dearth of Android-based solutions in the answers.

Comment: I guess it's not, but at the time of the question it was a novel function on Android devices and seemed particularly relevant to Android users.

Comment: Do you mean creating QR codes on an Android device itself?  If so, you may want to mention it in the question.

Comment: Here is simple and quick QR code generator: https://tool.tonytuan.org/#/QrCode . Just paste any text (such as URL) to the input and it will generate QR CODE immediately.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the **goo.gl URL shortener**: http://goo.gl/a4Wv and **adding a .qr** to the end of it: http://goo.gl/a4Wv.qr

Comment: Looks like it's not supported again. Firebase says: Invalid Dynamic Link

Answer (score 15):

The Google Charts API is definitely the easiest. You just make a URL as follows:

`https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=<content>&choe=UTF-8`

Content is usually a link, for example, this is a link to this site:

[image]

`https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https://android.stackexchange.com/&choe=UTF-8`

Answer (score 7):

You can also make ASCII QR codes (mainly for websites like Reddit): http://asciiqr.com/

Comment: While not the "easiest" way to make a QR code, it is certainly awesome!

Answer (score 2):

[KAYWA](http://qrcode.kaywa.com/)

easy as adding a link and click generate. Can generate for sms, text or phone numbers.

Comment: This is my favorite option as well because it can do more than typical url shortening service.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the url of the page your are viewing into a QR Code easily with these bookmarklets:

1. This one creates a pop-up where you can edit the url.  It's a two click process:

   `javascript:var sCode=prompt('Enter URL to encode',window.location);void(window.open('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl='+encodeURIComponent(sCode),'Qr code','top=100,left=200,width=350,height=350,status=yes'));`
2. This one is a one click and done process:

   `javascript:(function(){if(document.getElementById){var x=document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);var o=document.createElement('script');if(typeof(o)!='object') o=document.standardCreateElement('script');o.setAttribute('src','http://qrbookmarklet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/qr.js');o.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');x.appendChild(o);}})();`

Just create a bookmark in your Chrome or FF browser bar and paste the above code into the URL field of the bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an Android app that does that, try "**QR Droid**".

It lets you do this:
- In the Browser, when your viewing URL that you want to share, select "Menu" > "More" > "Share page" > "QR Droid"
- There, you'll be able to generate QR code with a click, and to optionally shorten it first so resulting QR code has less data an therefore is easier to read by decoders

After generating QR code, it allow you to share image or URL from Google Chart as text

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [QR Code Generator from the ZXing Project](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/).
It's a web app that quickly lets you enter in any text to create a QR code.

It will also allow you to enter structured info (URL's, Contact Info, Wifi-network credentials), and creates QR Codes from that. The benefit there is that you may have apps that are set up to handle structured data. 
E.g.: a URL QR code will automatically open up your web browser at that address. Contact QR codes will create a new contact in your address book, and so on.