# Where can I get the QR code for an app on the Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, qr-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the easiest way to create a QR code for a link?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-qr-code-for-a-link)

I searched the site, and I've searched google with no answer. Posting QR code images on a webpage is convenient, because a person can just point their phone at their screen to download a new app. Where can I get the QR code for an app on the Play Store?

Comment: There's also this question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755574/create-qr-code-to-app-in-market

Answer (score 5):

The QR codes are not provided on the play store. You can create the QR code yourself by pasting the url to the app in a generator like [goqr.me](http://goqr.me/#url).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a QR code of the play store apps from within the android itself, first install [QR Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr&hl=en). Then open play store from your android, click on any app and use the "share" option in the play store. Then select "QR Droid" in the list. This should get you the QR Code.